# How to use PolynomialFeatures and then StandardScaler in scikit-learn with ColumnTransformer and Pipeline?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

How to make the pipeline apply `PolynomialFeatures` and then `StandardScaler` to `x1`, `x2`, and all generated polynomial features?

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression


df = pd.DataFrame({"x1": [1, 2, 6], 
                   "x2": [3, 18, 41],
                   "x3": ["red", "red", "green"],
                   "y": [1, 1, 0]})

X = df[["x1", "x2", "x3"]]
y = df["y"]

ct = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[("poly", PolynomialFeatures(degree=2, include_bias=False), ["x1", "x2"]),
                  ("scaler", StandardScaler(), ["x1", "x2"]), # Should contain x1, x2, and PolynomialFeatures
                  ("ohe", OneHotEncoder(), ["x3"])])

pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[("transformer", ct),
                           ("classifier", LogisticRegression(class_weight="balanced"))])

pipeline.fit(X, y)
```